# I am trying to create a login page on android but when i run it the bottom content does not seem to show on my phone

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, user-interface

I am trying to create a login page on android but when I run it, the bottom content does not seem to show on my phone but it works fine on my tab, does anyone have a solution for this? I really don't know what layout to use. I am currently using a `RelativeLayout`.

This is the preview from Android Studio:

[image]

From my phone:

[image]

The text below the login button doesn't show on my phone

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="660dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/chimesignupbg" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/logo"
        android:layout_row="9"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/usernameEditText"
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:hint="  USERNAME"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/avatar"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passwordEditText"
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint=" PASSWORD"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/keyy"
        android:layout_below="@+id/usernameEditText"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/usernameEditText"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/usernameEditText"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp" />


    <Button
        android:text="LOG IN"
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:onClick="LoginButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/passwordEditText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp" />


    <TextView
        android:text="Don't have an account?"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="540dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text=" Sign up"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/signupLink"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: When your layout is too high for the screen you might use a `ScrollView` around it to allow it to be scrolled by the user. Can you provide us with a screenshot?

Comment: I have added an image to the post

Comment: Could you show what is visible on the phone?

Comment: DONE!! I HAVE POSTED IT

Comment: Your Phone simply is not high enough, you shouldn't rely on absolute measurements for your layout. If you want this huge spacing between the elements you should try the `ScrollView` approach.

Comment: ...but when i try using scrollview everything dissapears

Comment: Wrap everything in a `ScrollView`, make the ScrollView match_parent for height and width. In my opionion there is just too much spacing between some of your elements.

Comment: thanks i would try that or maybe try to reduce the spacing

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having the "Don't have an account" TextView as `android:layout_marginTop="540dp"` trying having it in relation to the loginButton `android:layout_below="@+id/loginButton"`

Comment: that was what i initially did, the android:layout_marginTop="540dp" was a solution to make it appear on my emulator, but my phone is different